# How do the movies shoot with character in multiple mirrors?

Tags: plot-explanation, screenplay

[image]

In movies how are these shots taken? With a character in multiple mirrors? sometimes in broken mirror pieces?

Answer (score 5):

In the photo you included, one possible way is this:

1. Hang the 12 mall mirrors on the wall.
2. Place the camera where it will be in the shot.
3. Have a "stand-in" stand right where the actor will be. (A "stand-in" is a person who is hired to stand in one place on a movie set, while technicians adjust the cameras and lights so that the person looks good. Then, the highly-paid actor takes the place of the stand-in before the scene is shot. Since the highly-paid actor is in the same place, he/she will be perfectly lit and framed.)
4. The prop master can then adjust the angles of all of the mirrors on the wall, so that all of them reflect the actor's head perfectly into the camera.
5. The scene can then be shot, and if the actor is in the right position then his head would be seen perfectly by the camera, just like the photo you included in your answer.